# Files not showing up in Nitrous.io desktop sync folder

Tags: nitrousio, mean.io

I loaded up the Nitrous.io desktop sync app and then installed the [mean.io](http://mean.io) stack on my box. For some reason I can't get any of the files to sync with my desktop. My keys are working fine, but there are no files syncing. There doesn't seem to be a lot of info in the docs on why this could be happening.

Answer (score 2):

The key thing is mentioned in the [Nitrous.io docs](http://help.nitrous.io/nitrous-desktop/) in this line:

```
"...the content within your ~/workspace/ folder will be synced into the newly created Nitrous folder once enabled."
```

This apparently means ONLY the stuff inside workspace (which is not root, so somewhat confusing) will be synced. So, a key missing step is that if you do anything outside the workspace folder, IT WILL NOT BE SYNCED. This includes installing frameworks or other software via the command line. You have to cd into the ~/workspace folder before installing anything or it won't be synced. Seems like a small thing to miss but it makes a big difference when nothing gets pulled down.

In the command line, type this before you install anything like node, bower, etc.

```
cd ~/workspace
```